# Access the scale option within TikZ environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

When using the scale option in `\tikz[xscale=2]` etc, is there any way to access the scale setting from within the TikZ environment?

Comment: Not the actual `xscale` passed in, but you can get the current transform matrix (ie the accumulation of all the transformations that you've specified).  Would that be sufficient to your needs?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you need but you can apply scale only to a block using `\begin{scope}[scale=2]...\end{scope}`.

Comment: Usually I do this : `\def\scaleFactor{2}\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\scaleFactor]...\end{tikzpicture}`

Then I can access it later using `\scaleFactor`. I would love to have a more elegant solution, especially if I have multiple scopes and scale factors.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I believe your comment is actually the answer.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I was waiting for clarification from the OP.  If kiwi really wants to know what was passed in via `xscale` then it could be done by hacking the `xscale` key, but if what kiwi wants to do could be accomplished by knowing the transform matrix then that's a better solution.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I think you should pop this one off and provide an answer with the transform matrix. I think it makes more sense anyways, and the question looks useful to me for further visitors.

Answer (score 6):

As Andrew says, you can use the transform matrix, which is an accumulation of all transformations currently applied to the current scope. The relevant details are found in Sections 104.2.1 and 104.2.4 of the [PGF Manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (v3.0.0).

I defined a command `\getmytransformmatrix` that stores PGF's internal representation of the transform matrix into the macros `\mya`, `\myb`, `\myc`, `\myd`, `\mys`, and `\myt`. These correspond to the coordinate transformation `(x,y) --> (a*x + b*y + s, c*x + d*y +t)`. So the accumulated `xscale` and `yscale` (global CS basis) are stored in `\mya` and `\myd`, respectively. Similarly, the dimensions `xshift` and `yshift` are stored in `\mys` and `\myt`, respectively.

These are not persistent across scope boundaries/levels, so the command `\getmytransformmatrix` must appear in every scope in which you wish to use the information.

**The Code (with brief illustration)**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\getmytransformmatrix{%
  \pgfgettransformentries{\mya}{\myb}{\myc}{\myd}{\mys}{\myt}%
% coordinate (x,y) is transformed to (ax + by + s, cx + dy + t)  
}

\newcommand\drawmyaxes[1][]{% just for convenience
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {$x#1$};
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,1) node[above] {$y#1$};
}

\newcommand\myvar[2]{\texttt{#1~=~#2}} % just for convenience

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=2pt]
  \getmytransformmatrix
  \drawmyaxes
  \node[align=left] at (-5,0) {Outside the scope, we have\\ 
    \myvar{xscale}{\mya}, \myvar{yscale}{\myd}.};
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-5pt,rotate=45]
    \getmytransformmatrix
    \drawmyaxes[']
    \node[align=left] at (-1,-1) {Inside the scope, we have\\ 
      \myvar{xscale}{\mya}, \myvar{yscale}{\myd}.\\
      We also see that \myvar{xshift}{\mys}\\
      and \myvar{yshift}{\myt}.};
  \end{scope}
  \node[align=left] at (5,0) {Outside the scope again, we have\\
    \myvar{xscale}{\mya}, \myvar{yscale}{\myd}.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]

Note that the matrix is not "remembered" outside the scope, and that this shows the accumulated transformation (`xshift=2pt` from the original environment *and* `yshift=-5pt` from the scope).

The additional variables `b` and `c` could be used for other calculations; for example, to compute the effective rotation (`atan(\myd/\mya)` would only work from (-90,90) ).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this depends on what your purpose is in saving the `xscale`.  There are two possibilities that I can think of:

1. You want to know what was passed in via `xscale`.
2. You want to know the `xscale` of the current scope.

The first is quite easy, the second depends on what you mean by `xscale`.

The reason that the first isn't trivial is because TikZ does not bother to save the value that you pass in, it simply applies it and then forgets it.  So you need to add a wrapper around the `xscale` key which saves the value for later use.  Here's some code for that:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151147/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  saved xscale/.initial=1,
  save xscale/.style={
    xscale=#1,
    save the xscale=#1
  },
  save the xscale/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{#1 * \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/saved xscale}}%
    \pgfkeysalso{saved xscale/.expand once=\pgfmathresult}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[save xscale=2]
\node at (0,0) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/saved xscale}};
\begin{scope}[save xscale=2]
\node at (1,0) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/saved xscale}};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\node at (2,0) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/saved xscale}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(This may not be the most elegant way to achieve this.)

The difficulties with the second are because TikZ can apply **any** affine transformation to parts of a drawing.  So you have to come up with a meaning for `xscale` for an arbitrary affine transformation.  Consider the two following scenarios:

1. You apply `xscale=2` and then apply a rotation of π/2 (anticlockwise).  The resulting matrix is

   ```
   [0 -1]
   [2  0]
   ```
2. You apply the rotation first and then do `yscale=2`.  The resulting matrix is

   ```
   [0 -1]
   [2  0]
   ```

So these two operations lead to the same matrix.  Does that matrix have `xscale` equal to `2` or `yscale` equal to `2`?  Or are both `0`?

Now consider doing the rotation and then `xscale=2`.  This yields:

```
[0 -2]
[1  0]
```

So for all of these scenarios you have to decide what `xscale` should be.  There are reasonable definitions, but precisely what will depend on what you want to do with them.

Thus the best you can do is to examine the matrix *as a whole* and compute some number that works for whatever it is that you want to do, but as this is not specified in the question then it is not feasible to answer that.

To get the entries of the matrix itself (well, the matrix and the translation), you can use the PGF command `\pgfgettransformentries`.  Then do what you like with them.  For example, if you want to know the *overall* scale, you could take the square root of the absolute value of its determinant.  If you want to know the length of the vector that `(1,0)` eventually becomes, you could compute that.

In summary:

1. To store the accumulated values passed to `xscale`, simply store them before passing them in,
2. To extract the `xscale` from the transformation matrix, use the PGF commands for accessing the matrix, figure out what you mean by `xscale` an arbitrary matrix, and then compute it from the retrieved values.