# Sloped Tikz node with rotation and scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, rotating, scaling

There should be an easy way to place a `sloped` `node` along a path. Using `sloped` works great (as in the black text). However, if there is a `rotate=` applied then the text is no longer *along* the path (as in the red and blue examples). I can get the correct direction if I use `transform shape` (as in the orange example), but then the text gets scaled if a `scale=` is being applied.

**Question:** How do I define the `\MyDraw` macro so that it can be used with a `rotate` *and* a `scale` such that:

- the text is along the path even if a `rotate=` is applied, and
- the text is *not* affected by a `scale=`.

[image]

### Notes:

- In my actual use, these drawing are all in the same `tikzpicture` and I use a `scope` to apply the desired transformations.  To keep the MWE as close to possible as my actual use case, I used `scope`s in the MWE below instead of applying the options to the `tikzpicture` itself.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\MyDraw}[1]{%
    \draw [ultra thick, -latex] (0,0) -- (1,4) 
        node [midway, above, sloped, align=center] {#1};
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \MyDraw{not rotated};
\end{tikzpicture}%
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation"
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=-25, red]
        \MyDraw{rotated};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation" and "scale"
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=-15, scale=1.3, blue]
        \MyDraw{rotated and scaled};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation", "scale" and "transform shape"
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=-15, scale=1.5, transform shape, orange]
        \MyDraw{rotated, scaled and \\ ``transform shape"};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using [this answer to question 162639](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162639/19042), you could use `\pgfgettransformentries{\mya}{\myb}{\myc}{\myd}{\mys}{\myt}` to guess the scale factor and then use it together with the `transform shape` key with `xscale=1/\mya,yscale=1/\myd`. It is working in your example, but I wonder if it will works in every cases (I mean with multiple transformations).

Comment: @remjg: Yep, that works well along with `transform shape`. You want to post that as an answer - I am going to use that unless an easier solution appears.

Comment: @remjg: Upon further testing it appears that that is not very precise. I tested it using the "unscaling" the text via the exact scale that I am applying and the size of the text is different as compared to using `mya` and `myd`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to place text on a straight line, one option is to explicitly calculate the angle, preceded by `\pgftransformreset`, and then rotate the node accordingly:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\def\getangle(#1)(#2)#3{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgftransformreset%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname angle#3\endcsname{\pgfmathresult}%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,1);
\getangle(A)(B)a;
\draw (A) -- node [midway,above,rotate=\anglea] {text} (B);
%%
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,rotate=30,yscale=1.3,xscale=1.5]
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);
\coordinate (D) at (1,1);
\getangle(C)(D)b;
\draw (C) -- node [midway,above,rotate=\angleb] {text} (D);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields

[image: result as png]

Your example would then be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\getangle(#1)(#2)#3{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgftransformreset%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname angle#3\endcsname{\pgfmathresult}%
  \endgroup%
}

\newcommand*{\MyDraw}[1]{%
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1,4);
    \getangle(A)(B)a
    \draw [ultra thick, -latex] (A) -- (B) 
        node [midway, above, rotate=\anglea, align=center] {#1};
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \MyDraw{not rotated};
\end{tikzpicture}%
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation"
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=-25, red]
        \MyDraw{rotated};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation" and "scale"
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=-15, scale=1.3, blue]
        \MyDraw{rotated and scaled};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Yielding

[image: second code compiled]

This approach does not work for `transform shape`, though.

Comment: Works great and does not require a change in how I do things.

Answer (score 10):

Use `nodes={rotate=<angle>}` instead `transform shape`:

In contrast to `transform shape` the `nodes={rotate=<angle>}` passes only the transformation *selected* by its argument (i.e. `rotate=<angle>`) to all nodes inside the scope.

Defining a new style `myrotate` as an abbreviation

```
\tikzset{
  myrotate/.style={rotate=#1,nodes={rotate=#1}}
}
```

and using `myrotate=<angle>` instead `rotate=<angle>` results in

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  myrotate/.style={rotate=#1,nodes={rotate=#1}}
}

\newcommand*{\MyDraw}[1]{%
    \draw [ultra thick, -latex] (0,0) -- (1,4) 
        node [midway, above, sloped, align=center] {#1};
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \MyDraw{not rotated};
\end{tikzpicture}%
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation"
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[myrotate=-25,red]
        \MyDraw{rotated};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation" and "scale"
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[myrotate=-15,scale=1.3, blue]
        \MyDraw{rotated and scaled};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation", "scale" and "transform shape"
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[myrotate=-15, scale=1.5, orange]
        \MyDraw{rotated, scaled and \\ ``transform shape"};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure if this solution will work for me as it require to pass the rotate information to every component of the figure. But as far as `rotate` not affecting a node, if you apply `transform shape` then you don't need to manually apply a rotate to the `node`.

Comment: If you use `transform shape` the nodes will also be scaled. But it is possible to use `every node/.append style` to pass the `rotate` option to *all* nodes inside the scope. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I used to write a linear algebra library for TikZ(mainly to handle complex numbers) but since now TikZ is using Lua extensively that became pretty much obsolete so I stopped it. Nevertheless here is a quick steal from the Givens QR decomposition for two by two matrix that separates the transformation matrix into scaling and rotation and we only use rotation part and omit the scale/slant part.

Same idea can be used to cancel the rotation and keep the scaling to answer the question in the comments. I'll have a look if I can spare more time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\MyDraw}[1]{%
    \draw [ultra thick, -latex] (0,0) -- (1,4) 
        node [midway, above, sloped, align=center,cancel scale] {#1};
}%
\tikzset{cancel scale/.code=\pgfmathcancelscale}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathcancelscale{%
  \pgfgettransformentries{\my@a}{\my@b}{\my@c}{\my@d}{\my@xi}{\my@yi}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\my@cos{\my@a/veclen(\my@a,\my@c)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\my@sin{-\my@c/veclen(\my@a,\my@c)}%
  \pgfsettransformentries{\my@cos}{\my@sin}{-\my@sin}{\my@cos}{\my@xi}{\my@yi}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=-15, scale=1.5, transform shape, orange]
        \MyDraw{rotated, scaled and \\ ``transform shape"};
            \begin{scope}[rotate=40, scale=0.2, shift={(10cm,-5cm)},transform shape, blue]
            \MyDraw{rotated, scaled and \\ ``transform shape"};
            \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works well except that it also affects the placement of the text, and hence requires manually moving the text.

Comment: @PeterGrill Oops. I just saw that :) Let me see

Comment: @PeterGrill It's because of the timer gets also affected (which controls the `pos=<num>` stuff). I have to isolate it but it will be some time later :)

Comment: This would be an ideal solution if the node placement wasn't so out of whack.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm getting there slowly. It took some time to get what is happening. I need to hack in somewhere. Don't know yet :)

Answer (score 5):

As a follow up to my comment, here is what I have tried using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162639/19042) from the question [Access the scale option within TikZ environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151147/access-the-scale-option-within-tikz-environment).

I would define a new key `Sloped` that guess the `xscale` and `yscale` factor to cancel scaling while using `sloped` and `transform shape` to keep the rotation:

```
\tikzset{
  Sloped/.code=%
  \pgfgettransformentries{\mya}{\myb}{\myc}{\myd}{\mys}{\myt}%
  \tikzset{sloped, transform shape, xscale=1/\mya, yscale=1/\myd}%  
}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
  Sloped/.code=%
  \pgfgettransformentries{\mya}{\myb}{\myc}{\myd}{\mys}{\myt}%
  \tikzset{sloped, transform shape, xscale=1/\mya, yscale=1/\myd}%  
}%

\newcommand*{\MyDraw}[1]{%
    \draw [ultra thick, -latex] (0,0) -- (70:5) 
        node [midway, above, Sloped, align=center] {#1};
}%

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \MyDraw{not rotated};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  %--------------------------------- apply "rotation"
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}[rotate=-25, red]
          \MyDraw{rotated};
      \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  % --------------------------------- apply "rotation" and "scale"
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}[rotate=-15, scale=1.3, blue]
          \MyDraw{rotated and scaled};
      \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  % --------------------------------- apply "rotation", "scale" and "transform shape"
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}[rotate=-15, scale=1.5, transform shape, orange]
          \MyDraw{rotated, scaled and \\ ``transform shape"};
      \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

### Problem

As mentioned by Peter Grill in the comment, it doesn't work very well, the text is a bit smaller. I remove my answer as soon as someone tell me why it doesn't work ;-)

[image: Problem comparing with the exact output]

Comment: That's indeed the way to go for pure scaling but it doesn't work with slanted versions. And don't remove it. It's nice : ) That much TeX arithmetic is acceptable

Comment: I don't understand the difference between scaling and slanted, can you shed some light on this?

Comment: add `yslant=0.4` etc. to see the effect. They are the off diagonal terms in the transformation matrix. So if you have `[2 0.5;0 3]` as the transformation matrix multiplying the coordinate `[x;y]`, that means multiply `x` by two and add half of `y` to it. So things get parallelogramed as the scaling is not purely `xscale=2,yscale=3`if something else sets a trafo matrix, @esdd answer also goes awry.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is an improvement of [Jonathan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299634/108208). It's easy to use by calling the option `Sloped` instead of `sloped`. `transform shape` is supported.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
Sloped/.code = {
\iftikz@fullytransformed% tikz.code.tex
    \tikzset{sloped}
\else
    \pgfgettransformentries{\mya}{\myb}{\myc}{\myd}{\mys}{\myt}%
    \tikzset{sloped, rotate = {atan2(\myb,\mya)}}%
\fi
}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\MyDraw}[1]{
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (60:4);
\draw [ultra thick, -latex] (A) -- (B) node [midway, above, Sloped, align=center] {#1};% Sloped instead of sloped
}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,10,...,360}{% test a list of angles
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-7.5,-7.5) rectangle (7.5,7.5);
\MyDraw{not rotated};
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation"
\begin{scope}[rotate=15+\i, red]
\MyDraw{rotated};
\end{scope}
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation" and "scale"
\begin{scope}[rotate=30+\i, scale=1.3, blue]
\MyDraw{rotated and scaled};
\end{scope}
% --------------------------------- apply "rotation", "scale" and "transform shape"
\begin{scope}[rotate=45+\i, scale=1.5, transform shape, orange]
\MyDraw{rotated, scaled and \\ ``transform shape"};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]